# What should I call a balance sheet that doesn't balance?

Tags: single-word-requests

One of the fundamental accounting/financial statements is the [balance sheet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_sheet). A balance sheet is balanced because the total assets of a company equal their liabilities plus owners' equity. However, what should a balance sheet that doesn't balance be called? Would that be an imbalance sheet, unbalance sheet, unbalanced sheet, or something else?

Comment: For me that's "normal".

Comment: @HotLicks: Your comment made asking this question worthwhile.

Comment: It would be called "faulty" because a balance sheet is contrived to balance.

Comment: It is still a balance sheet, even if it does not balance. However, the situation will never arise. If, for example, there is an unaccountable deficit of £40,000, then the balance would be made by entering "unaccountable deficit of £40,000" in the liability column.

Comment: How do you fix an unbalanced balance sheet? https://marqueegroup.ca/resource/dont-lose-your-balance-a-foolproof-method-to-balancing-balance-sheets/ -

Comment: "Balance" -- you know, what's in your bank account, that gets to be negative when you bounce a check :) "Balance" does not have to mean the company is doing well.

Comment: I guess it's a sheet.

Comment: I have it on good authority (an office full of accountants) that there is no technical term

Comment: With ERPs it's technically impossible to have one that doesn't balance (Debit = Credit check at journal posting). The most you can have is technical accounts that aren't net 0, those count as *plug accounts* in the clearing process. You don't have a balance sheet before your *trial balance* is prepared by clearing those pesky plug accounts. From there you should just link those accounts to the BS and then do adjustments for some outliers (AR with credit balance etc). At literally no point do you have an *unbalanced balance sheet*.

Comment: @Naomi Quite so, an "unbalanced balance sheet" does not mean you have made a loss. It means there is an error somewhere. Even a business making substantial losses must have a balance sheet which balances. Otherwise there has been an error somewhere.

Comment: It's still a *balance sheet*. It's using the noun not the verb. A device used to determine if something balances, making no claim that it *is* balanced.

Answer (score 11):

It seems silly to have to say this, but you should call it what it is: an **unbalanced balance sheet**. And, clearly, given the definition of *balance sheet*, there can only be an **unbalanced balance sheet** if there is an error of some kind in the balance sheet: an error in the total assets of the company, the company's liabilities, the owners' equity, and whatever other pluses and minuses come into play. As @Greybeard has indicated in his comment, you could avoid the existence of an imbalance by including in the balance sheet an unaccountable deficit (or surplus) line. That would result in a *balanced balance sheet* in all cases, i.e., a balance sheet that actually balances. At the same time, it would indicate the existence of a problem (if the unaccountable deficit or surplus were significant) while shedding no light on the origin of the problem.

Answer (score 8):

To be a hair more serious, one might say that the balance sheet has a "[discrepancy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/discrepancy)":

> a difference between two things that should be the same

Comment: 'The balance sheet [does not balance]' = 'The balance sheet *has a discrepancy*.'

Answer (score 4):

You can use the expression “***unbalanced balance sheet***.”

M-W defines ***[unbalanced](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unbalanced)*** as:

> c : not adjusted so as to make credits equal to debits - *an unbalanced account*.

The are numerous usage examples of unbalanced used referring to a balance sheet such as:

> How to Review an Unbalanced Balance Sheet. ([smallbusiness.chron.com](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/review-unbalanced-balance-sheet-35567.html)
>
> 5 Reasons Why Your Balance Sheet Is Unbalanced. ([atsaccountinginc.com](https://www.atsaccountinginc.com/our-blog/5-reasons-why-your-balance-sheet-is-unbalanced))
>
> Unbalanced Balance Sheet & Trial Balance. 
>   ([community.myob.com](https://community.myob.com/t5/AccountRight-Getting-started/Unbalanced-Balance-Sheet-amp-Trial-Balance/td-p/554511))